# Display Json in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, parsing

Im having problems trying to display in my view information comming from a json file. I have already parse it.

Here is my error:

```
When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.
Extracted source (around line #23):

21 # @new_member.constructors = [driver['Constructors'][0]['name']]
22      # @new_member.points = [driver['points']]
23      @new_member.from_json(json)

        @members << @new_member
    end

        # @new_member.constructors = [driver['Constructors'][0]['name']]
        # @new_member.points = [driver['points']]
        @new_member.from_json(json)

        @members << @new_member
    end
```

This is my controller:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

url = "http://ergast.com/api/f1/2014/driverStandings.json"
data = JSON.parse(open(url).read)
standings = data['MRData']['StandingsTable']['StandingsLists'][0]['DriverStandings']

@members = Array.new
standings.each do |driver|
    json = standings.to_json
    @new_member = Member.new
    # @new_member.position = [driver['position']]
    # @new_member.givenName = [driver['Driver']['givenName']]
    # @new_member.familyName = [driver['Driver']['familyName']]
    # @new_member.constructors = [driver['Constructors'][0]['name']]
    # @new_member.points = [driver['points']]
    @new_member.from_json(json)

    @members << @new_member
```

If I uncommented the lines in the controller and delete these lines

```
@new_member.from_json(json)
json = standings.to_json
```

I get the following in the view

Name: ["Lewis"]

Name: ["Nico"]

That view is really close but is not what i need, I need the data without [" "], 
so the view that I need is something like:

1 Lewis Hamilton Mercedes 384

Thanks in advance.

Comment: small comment. you've given us too much information to be helpful for a question suggesting how to display json. try the 'awesome_print' gem

Comment: Sorry, I just try to make as clear as I could. What can I do with that gem?

Comment: You've basically given us a dump of your app. Please try to narrow the question down to specifics. You seem to have multiple questions: are you having trouble parsing JSON? Assembling data for a view? Designing a view for the data? Please limit your question and prune your code down to the minimal that exhibits the problem.

Comment: My apologise, I have edited the answer and try to reduce a bit. My problem is the erro that it can be seen above.

Comment: What is in your `json` variable?

Comment: What im trying to do is....   @new_member.from_json(standings.to_json)

Im sure that should be an easy way do do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Alternative 1

Change the line:

`@new_member.givenName = [driver['Driver']['givenName']]`

into:

`@new_member.givenName = driver['Driver']['givenName']`

removing the external `[` and `]`, so that the field `@new_member.givenName` that you're populating becomes a string rather than an array containing one string.

## Alternative 2

Is it possible that, when looping through the `standings` hash, the `driver` temp variable is a Hash?

In this case it may be sufficient to do:

`@members = Array.new
    standings.each do |driver|
        @members << Member.new(driver)
    end`

Bonus: you probably don't need to assign an instance variable `@new_member`, that gets overwritten at each iteration of the loop

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. The first one works perfect. The second gives error.